# Test if relative path will move upward

Tags: java

I'm given a relative path from the user and at the time it's given I don't know what it's relative to. All I want to do is make sure that it doesn't "escape" from where ever I decide to make it relative to, i.e., it's not an absolute path, and won't change directories upward high enough to go beyond the starting point.

For instance `foo.html` is fine, and `foo/bar/../baz.html` is fine, even `foo/bar/../../baz.html`, but not `foo/bar/../../../baz.html` because that goes up too high.

Now this is relatively easy if I know that `/` is the directory separator and `..` is the "chup" specifier, but I want to do it in a platform independent way in Java. It looks like Java already knows the necessary information, because it does things like canonicalization of paths in `java.io.File`, but I can't find a way to "canonicalize" a path that is truly relative.

Comment: There's something like a DirectorySeparatorChar or something in Java.  I'm not sure if there's a similar thing for the `..`.

Comment: Are there any systems where .. isn't the "up one directory" specifier?

Comment: @KevinWorkman None I'm aware of, but that's the whole point: I'm not aware of it. Unknown unknowns and all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`java.nio.file.Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#compareTo(java.nio.file.Path)) if you're using Java 7+:

```
String suspiciousPath = "foo/bar/../../../baz.html";

Path current = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize();
Path test = current.resolve(suspiciousPath).toAbsolutePath().normalize();

System.out.println(current); // /home/vw5Vv0
System.out.println(test);    // /home/baz.html

boolean valid = test.startsWith(current);

System.out.println(valid ? "OK" : "DANGEROUS"); // DANGEROUS
```

PS. There's no need for `.toAbsolutePath().normalize()` calls - they're there just for the clarity.

Comment: Thanks, that's nearly perfect, except it still allows a user to submit a path that happens to be inside my working directory. I was able to resolve that by testing it against _both_ `./1` and `./2` using the technique you showed.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand you correctly. Isn't `./1.txt` a valid path?

Comment: I mean I'm using `current1 = Paths.get(".").resolve("1")` and `current2 = Paths.get(".").resolve("2")` and then resolving and checking the `suspiciousPath` against both `current1` and `current2` the same way you check it against `current`. So that, for instance if they submit `/home/vw5Vv0/foo`, it will fail. Where as it will succeed if I only check it against `/home/vw5Vv0`.

Answer (score 0):

You're testing two things:

1. The "source" path (the path things should be relative to) should NOT start with the test path.
2. The test path SHOULD start with the "source" path.

This seems to do the trick:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

       File sourcePathFile = new File("./");

       String testPath = "../../";

       File testPathFile = new File(testPath);

       boolean valid = (!sourcePathFile.getCanonicalPath().startsWith(testPathFile.getCanonicalPath())) && testPathFile.getCanonicalPath().startsWith(sourcePathFile.getCanonicalPath());

       System.out.println("Relative to: " + sourcePathFile.getCanonicalPath());
       System.out.println("Path: " + testPathFile.getCanonicalPath());
       System.out.println("Valid: " + valid);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the library of apache "filenameUtils"

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html

It have a method called "normalize" who do exactly what you want

Example:

```
FilenameUtils.normalize("foo/bar/.."); // =>  foo/
```

This class supports Unix and Windows style names